# fabric: why can't I get local("history") to print out anything?

Tags: python-2.7, fabric, macos-sierra

Here's my fabfile

```
from fabric.api import local, task

@task
def tracking(suffix=""):

    buffer_ = "*" * 40
    print (buffer_)
    local("whoami")
    print (buffer_)
    local("env | grep dn")

    #this one comes out empty...
    print (buffer_)
    out = local("history")
    print (buffer_)
```

Everything prints out as expected, except for the **history**:

```
****************************************
[localhost] local: whoami
jluc
****************************************
[localhost] local: env | grep dn
dn_cb=/Users/jluc/.berkshelf/cookbooks
dn_cc=/Users/jluc/kds2/chef/chef-repo/cookbooks
dn_khtmldump=/Users/jluc/kds2/out/tests/dump2static
dn_cv=/Users/jluc/kds2/chef/vagrant/ubuntu2
****************************************
[localhost] local: history
****************************************
```

But nothing wrong with history on the command line...

`history | tail -5`

```
  613  history
  614  fab -f fabfile2.py tracking
  615  history | tail -5
  616  cls
  617  history | tail -5
```

What gives?  Adding `shell="/bin/bash"` didn't help either.

MacOs Sierra

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.local):

> local is not currently capable of simultaneously printing and capturing output, as run/sudo do. The capture kwarg allows you to switch between printing and capturing as necessary, and defaults to False.

I'd interpret this as meaning if you want the `history` command to work, you need to capture the output first.  Try changing all your `local` commands to include both `shell="/bin/bash"`, and `capture=True`

Comment: I tried both capture and bin/bash and that didn't help.  But, only with **history** does it not work.  I don't really need the capture, as I am using a **>** redirect.  `subprocess.check_output("history")` also didn't work.  So I ended up doing it directly in a bash function that calls fab *and* history.